# When webscraping with python and Beautifulsoup adding a class to a findAll() search brings back zero results?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to coding in general. To be brief I am using the `soup.findAll('table')` function and it brings back all the tables on the web page. When I search `soup.findAll('table', class_='playerTable rtable')` it brings back `[]`. I know that that is the correct class name as I copied it from the HTML. Do you guys know why this might be happening? What am I missing here?

url I'm attempting to scrape from http://www.spotrac.com/nfl/denver-broncos/peyton-manning-5028/

The reason you guys don't see the same table as me is because you need to be signed in to an account, that costs money to for the access to the information, my question still stands, why might this be happening? When I know there is a table with the class I am searching for. Thanks so much for the help guys!

Comment: Could you post the URL that you are attempting to scrape from?

Comment: http://www.spotrac.com/nfl/denver-broncos/peyton-manning-5028/

Comment: @TylerAnderson i don't see any class named "playerTable rtable". Can you please give me some info about what part of the physical page you are referring to so i can right click on it and do an inspect element.

Comment: @TylerAnderson i only see a class named "playerTable"

Comment: Sure, for example if you right-click any of the years that are in the table like 2012, it pulls you to an 'a href' which is in a td, which is in a tr (salaryRow) which is in the tbody, which is in a bunch of other things but up there is <table class="playerTable rtable">. I want to find all of those playerTable rtable's .

Comment: @TylerAnderson can you please tell us, if you don't mind, about exactly what data you're trying to extract from that HTML script?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because no table on this [page](http://www.spotrac.com/nfl/denver-broncos/peyton-manning-5028/) has both classes **playerTable** and **rtable**. And `soup.findAll('table', class_='playerTable rtable')` is an AND operation ie it will fetch *table* elements with both the classes, hence empty list.

EDIT: Finally the main reason for this behaviour was because of the unauthenticated request used to fetch html. Therefore no table containing the specified classes existed.

Comment: so would `soup.findAll('table', class_='rtable')` bring me the tables that say 'playerTable rtable' in the html?

Comment: No `soup.findAll('table', class_='rtable')` will bring tables with rtable class but `soup.findAll('table', class_='playerTable rtable')` will bring tables with both the classes.

Comment: but in the html the table I'm looking for is `<table class="playerTable rtable">` which lists both playerTable and rtable as classes. Isn't that what I want? To search for a table with both classes?

Comment: Yes but I couldn't find any table with both the classes  in the html page to which the link you provided.

Comment: Here is a comment that I left on the question portion about where I find what I'm looking for through inspect element.
"Sure, for example if you right-click any of the years that are in the table like 2012, it pulls you to an 'a href' which is in a td, which is in a tr (salaryRow) which is in the tbody, which is in a bunch of other things but up there is <table class="playerTable rtable">. I want to find all of those playerTable rtable's "

Comment: @TylerAnderson firstly, there is no year 2012 in the link you gave. There is only the year 2016. Also, when you look at where the "a href" is nested inside of, you see can that it's inside the class "playerTable". There is no "playerTable rtable" class. I did a thorough search through the whole HTML script.

Comment: In the first link that I refered to there was no such table, but the new link you provided in last comment there was the table that you mentioned.

Comment: If you want to select the table you can also use select method to use css selector. `soup.select('table.playerTable .rtable')`

Comment: OH!!! Sorry guys, you have to have an account to see the contract information!! I forgot that. But my question still remains, why might the find all not work.

Comment: You just answered the question, probably because when you are fetching the html, it is an unauthenticated request and hence does not have that table

Comment: @TylerAnderson exactly what jat said.

Comment: OH MY!!! yes! how could I be so stupid! I have another code that logs me in!! I'm so sorry to waste your guys' time. You were all so helpful!!!! Sorry...

Comment: @TylerAnderson Glad to help.

Comment: @TylerAnderson Yeah no problem. Just be careful the next time you post something so other people don't spend so much time on something that doesn't exist :). I see you're new to stack overflow. Welcome and good luck

Comment: @BOi Yeah, sorry I've been stuck on this problem for the last three hours, I really didn't want to make a post because I figured it'd be something stupid which it was but I could not figure out what was wrong. Thanks to everybody! You're great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any class named "playerTable rtable" for the link you provided. Maybe you can try this and let me know if it was what you needed. Happy to delete/change my answer if it doesn't work out for you:

```
>>> r = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.spotrac.com/nfl/denver-broncos/peyton-manning-5028/").content, "lxml")
>>> r.findAll("table", attrs = {"class":"playerTable"})
[<table class="playerTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="contract-type">
<div>
<h2>
<span class="contract-type-logo"><img alt="Team contract signed with" src="http://d1dglpr230r57l.cloudfront.net/images/thumb/broncos.png"/></span>
<span class="contract-type-years">2016-2016 <small>Dead Money</small></span>
</h2>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>, <table class="playerTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right:5px;">
<table class="salaryTable rtable current">
<thead>
<tr class="salaryRow">
<th class="header center">Year</th>
<th class="header center"> </th>
<th class="header salaryAmt center "><span>Base Salary</span></th>
<th class="header salaryAmt center"><span title="">Signing Bonus</span></th> <th class="header salaryAmt center"><span>Workout Bonus</span></th> <th class="header salaryAmt center"><span title="">Restruc. Bonus</span></th> <th class="header salaryAmt center"><span>Dead Cap Hit</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="salaryRow">
<td class="salaryYear center"><a href="http://www.spotrac.com/redirect/team/9/cap-2016/">2016</a></td>
<td class="salaryYear center"><img alt="Player contract details by year" src="http://d1dglpr230r57l.cloudfront.net/images/thumb/broncos.png"/></td>
<td class="salaryAmt ">-</td>
<td class="salaryAmt ">-</td> <td class="salaryAmt ">-</td> <td class="salaryAmt ">$2,500,000</td> <td class="salaryAmt ">$2,500,000</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>]
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is under the 'div' with the class 'tablewrap' it is a table that in the html is labeled "<table class='playerTable rtable"> == $0